# asp.net C# Gridview contains data but only returning cell value = ""

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datatable

i got the following problem.
i have a ASP.NET Gridview which contains 12 columns (one for each month) and only one row to display values of type 'double' matching these columns based on a sql query.

[GridView with data based on the their date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sr0a7.png)

Here i provide you the snippet that executes the query to receive the matching data. This works fine as you can see in the image above.

```
protected void LoadZusammenfassung()
{
    List<string> tempList = new List<string>();
    DataTable dt_zusammenfassung = new DataTable();

    int countEmpty = 0;

    //Erstellen der DataTable für die Monatszusammenfassung (12 Spalten)
    for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++)
    {
        dt_zusammenfassung.Columns.Add(i.ToString(), typeof(Double));
    }

    using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(MDE_ConnectionString))
    {
        con.Open();

        //Durchläuft die Monate 1-12 um die summierten Überstunden den einzelnen Spalten zuordnen zu können
        for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++)
        {
            _query_zusammenfassung = "SELECT SUM(Anz_ueberstunden) FROM ERP WHERE Month(Ueberstundendatum) = '" + i.ToString() + "'";

            if (DDL_user.SelectedValue != "Alle Benutzer")
            {
                _query_zusammenfassung = _query_zusammenfassung + " AND UserName = '" + DDL_user.SelectedValue + "'";
            }
            if (DDL_year.SelectedValue != "Gesamter Zeitraum")
            {
                _query_zusammenfassung = _query_zusammenfassung + " AND YEAR(Ueberstundendatum) = '" + DDL_year.SelectedValue + "'";
            }

            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(_query_zusammenfassung, con))
            {
                using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        if (reader.HasRows)
                        {
                            if (reader[0] == null || reader[0] == DBNull.Value)
                            {
                                //tempList.Add("0.00");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                tempList.Add(reader[0].ToString());
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        dt_zusammenfassung.Rows.Add(tempList.ToArray());

        foreach(string item in tempList)
        {
            if(item == "" || item == DBNull.Value.ToString() || item == null)
            {
                countEmpty++;
            }
        }

        if (countEmpty < 12)
        {
            gridView_zusammenfassung.DataSource = dt_zusammenfassung;
            gridView_zusammenfassung.DataBind();
        }

        UpdatePanelZusammenfassung.Update();
    }
}
```

After this i want to analyse the data in the gridview for some criteria like "is any value greater than 20". This happens in the DataBound event of the gridview.

```
protected void gridView_zusammenfassung_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double CellValue;

    foreach (GridViewRow row in gridView_zusammenfassung.Rows)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < gridView_zusammenfassung.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            string Value = row.Cells[i].Text;
            //string Value = Convert.ToString(gridView_zusammenfassung.Rows[row.RowIndex].Cells[0].Text);

            if (double.TryParse(Value, out CellValue))
            {
                if (CellValue > 20)
                {
                    row.Cells[i].ForeColor = Color.Red;
                    row.Cells[i].Font.Bold = true;
                }
            }
            //else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(row.Cells[i].Text))
            //{
            //    row.Cells[i].Text = "-";
            //}
        }
    }
}
```

And there is the problem. The "row.Cells[i].Text" always returns and empty string like "". I have no idea what this could be.

-- EDIT --

I don't know if it helps but here is the html part of the gridview in the Updatepanel

```
<%-- GridView Zusammenfassung --%>
        <td style="padding-left:20px; padding-top:36px;">
            <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePanelZusammenfassung" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                <ContentTemplate>
                        <div runat="server" class="gridview" style="overflow-y:hidden; width:1500px; display:inline;">
                            <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gridView_zusammenfassung" AllowPaging="false" CssClass="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#009933" AutoGenerateColumns="false" HeaderStyle-BackColor="Green" OnDataBound="gridView_zusammenfassung_DataBound">

                                <Columns>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-Height="57px" ItemStyle-Height="50px" HeaderStyle-CssClass="GridLines2" Visible="true" ItemStyle-CssClass="GridLines2" FooterStyle-CssClass="GridLines2" HeaderText="Jan" HeaderStyle-Wrap="false" FooterStyle-Wrap="false" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" ItemStyle-Width="100px">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:Label ID="lbl_jan" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("1")%>' />
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>

                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-CssClass="GridLines2" Visible="true" ItemStyle-CssClass="GridLines2" FooterStyle-CssClass="GridLines2" HeaderText="Feb" HeaderStyle-Wrap="false" FooterStyle-Wrap="false" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" ItemStyle-Width="100px">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:Label ID="lbl_feb" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("2")%>' />
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>

                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-CssClass="GridLines2" Visible="true" ItemStyle-CssClass="GridLines2" FooterStyle-CssClass="GridLines2" HeaderText="Mär" HeaderStyle-Wrap="false" FooterStyle-Wrap="false" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" ItemStyle-Width="100px">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:Label ID="lbl_mar" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("3")%>' />
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>

                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-CssClass="GridLines2" Visible="true" ItemStyle-CssClass="GridLines2" FooterStyle-CssClass="GridLines2" HeaderText="Apr" HeaderStyle-Wrap="false" FooterStyle-Wrap="false" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" ItemStyle-Width="100px">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:Label ID="lbl_apr" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("4")%>' />
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>

                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-CssClass="GridLines2" Visible="true" ItemStyle-CssClass="GridLines2" FooterStyle-CssClass="GridLines2" HeaderText="Mai" HeaderStyle-Wrap="false" FooterStyle-Wrap="false" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" ItemStyle-Width="100px">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:Label ID="lbl_mai" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("5")%>' />
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>

                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-CssClass="GridLines2" Visible="true" ItemStyle-CssClass="GridLines2" FooterStyle-CssClass="GridLines2" HeaderText="Jun" HeaderStyle-Wrap="false" FooterStyle-Wrap="false" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" ItemStyle-Width="100px">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:Label ID="lbl_jun" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("6")%>' />
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>

                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-CssClass="GridLines2" Visible="true" ItemStyle-CssClass="GridLines2" FooterStyle-CssClass="GridLines2" HeaderText="Jul" HeaderStyle-Wrap="false" FooterStyle-Wrap="false" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" ItemStyle-Width="100px">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:Label ID="lbl_jul" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("7")%>' />
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>

                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-CssClass="GridLines2" Visible="true" ItemStyle-CssClass="GridLines2" FooterStyle-CssClass="GridLines2" HeaderText="Aug" HeaderStyle-Wrap="false" FooterStyle-Wrap="false" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" ItemStyle-Width="100px">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:Label ID="lbl_aug" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("8")%>' />
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>

                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-CssClass="GridLines2" Visible="true" ItemStyle-CssClass="GridLines2" FooterStyle-CssClass="GridLines2" HeaderText="Sep" HeaderStyle-Wrap="false" FooterStyle-Wrap="false" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" ItemStyle-Width="100px">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:Label ID="lbl_sep" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("9")%>' />
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>

                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-CssClass="GridLines2" Visible="true" ItemStyle-CssClass="GridLines2" FooterStyle-CssClass="GridLines2" HeaderText="Okt" HeaderStyle-Wrap="false" FooterStyle-Wrap="false" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" ItemStyle-Width="100px">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:Label ID="lbl_okt" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("10")%>' />
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>

                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-CssClass="GridLines2" Visible="true" ItemStyle-CssClass="GridLines2" FooterStyle-CssClass="GridLines2" HeaderText="Nov" HeaderStyle-Wrap="false" FooterStyle-Wrap="false" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" ItemStyle-Width="100px">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:Label ID="lbl_nov" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("11")%>' />
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>

                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-CssClass="GridLines2" Visible="true" ItemStyle-CssClass="GridLines2" FooterStyle-CssClass="GridLines2" HeaderText="Dez" HeaderStyle-Wrap="false" FooterStyle-Wrap="false" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" ItemStyle-Width="100px">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:Label ID="lbl_dez" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("12")%>' />
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                </Columns>

                                <EmptyDataTemplate>
                                    Keine Daten vorhanden.
                                </EmptyDataTemplate>
                        </asp:GridView>
                    </div>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </td>
```

Comment: have you debugged it to see if the row actually contains anything?

Comment: Yeah, just because of the debugging i knew that the "row.Cells[i].Text" contains an empty string

Comment: Is the row itself empty? does this have all expected values? gridView_zusammenfassung

Comment: When i debug the "System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableCellCollection" contains 12 cells and the gridview.rows counts one row

Comment: Are you excluding header row? It might not be an item row at all.

Comment: @TanveerBadar sry, what du you mean with "excluding header row"? in the for-loop it only loops through one row.

Comment: IIRC, GridView.Rows returns all rows which includes the header row. It might be possible that the only row your loop goes through is the header row. Are you sure your data table contains data?

Comment: As you can see in the image i linked above the data is provided to the gridview

Comment: @TanveerBadar and if the loop only goes through the header row shouldn't it return their values (Text) anyway? this row isn't empty too

Comment: You have not shared HeaderTemplate, I can only guess. You should attach a debugger and check RowType (or was it ItemType) properties to make sure you are not iterating over header row.

Comment: If you are using autogenerated columns, the Cell Text will be empty.

Comment: @VDWWD the AutoGenerateColumns property is set to 'false'

Comment: Is it possible, that the data is set unnaturally to the datatable? So the data is displayed but its behaviour is any other?

Comment: @J.Schaefer you should parameterize your query. If somebody would submit different values for you Dropdownlist `DDL_user` you would be in deep trouble. Just think what would happen if selected values would be `"foo OR 1=1; drop table users;"` SQL Parameters protect you from such attacks. Think of little bobby tables: https://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: @Marco yeah i always parameterize them if it makes sense. This is just a Dropdownlist of fixed values. this list isn't editable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the answer to this question...

i was a little bit kinda dumb :)

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-Height="57px" ItemStyle-Height="50px" HeaderStyle-CssClass="GridLines2" Visible="true" ItemStyle-CssClass="GridLines2" FooterStyle-CssClass="GridLines2" HeaderText="Jan" HeaderStyle-Wrap="false" FooterStyle-Wrap="false" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" ItemStyle-Width="100px"> 
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lbl_jan" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Jan")%>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

in this part you can see that i use asp:labels to keep my values and handle them.

So the reason why i can't receive these values in cells was just because they never were there. They were kept all the time in these labels.

i just needed to use the following line to query through all these labels

```
string CurrentLblValue = (gridView_zusammenfassung.Rows[row.RowIndex].FindControl("lbl_" + gridView_zusammenfassung.Columns[i].HeaderText.ToLower()) as Label).Text;
```